# How to check if part of an element exist in array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like this

```
['MLPClassifier-81991331-57fe-40f8-86b2-fa570e8a9010', 'RandomForestClassifier-fbf96287-c16b-4e1e-ba10-66d5747742c7', 'KNeighborsClassifier-34f6b483-618f-407a-88bb-902972db40db']
```

If I declare

```
 model = 'KNeighborsClassifier'
```

I need to check if there is an element start with above "model" and need to print the whole part as

```
 'KNeighborsClassifier-34f6b483-618f-407a-88bb-902972db40db'
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Do you know how to write a `for` loop? Do you know that there is a string method called `startswith`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple loop with an `if`-clause testing `str.startswith`:

```
array = ['MLPClassifier-81991331-57fe-40f8-86b2-fa570e8a9010', 
         'RandomForestClassifier-fbf96287-c16b-4e1e-ba10-66d5747742c7', 
         'KNeighborsClassifier-34f6b483-618f-407a-88bb-902972db40db']

model = 'KNeighborsClassifier'

for x in array:
    if x.startswith(model):
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try list comprehension:

```
a = ['MLPClassifier-81991331-57fe-40f8-86b2-fa570e8a9010', 
     'RandomForestClassifier-fbf96287-c16b-4e1e-ba10-66d5747742c7', 
     'KNeighborsClassifier-34f6b483-618f-407a-88bb-902972db40db']

model = 'KNeighborsClassifier'

[s for s in a if s.startswith(model)] # -> ['KNeighborsClassifier-34f6b483-618f-407a-88bb-902972db40db']
```